# jQuery: populate a textbox with the value of the span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7vcZT/

As you can see it works, but when you click the text and it turns into a textbox there are two problems:

1. The old text is not showing in the textbox and
2. if you click away by accident without entering anything then it completely disappears instead of showing the old text.

So,  (when a person clicks the text and the textbox appears) how do I get the value of the `SPAN` to show in the textbox?

Thanks!

Code in case you don't want to visit the fiddle:

```
$(".editDIV").click(function(){
    $(this).find("span")[0].style.display="none";
    $(this).find("input")[0].style.display="block";
    $(this).find("input")[0].focus();
});

$(".editINPUT").blur(function(){
    $(this)[0].style.display="none";
    $(this).prev()[0].innerText=$(this)[0].value;
    $(this).prev().show();
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the text from the span with `.text()` and insert him to the value of the input `.val()`

http://jsfiddle.net/7vcZT/16/

```
$(".editDIV").click(function(){
    $(this).find("input").val($(this).find('span').text());
    $(this).find("span")[0].style.display="none";
    $(this).find("input")[0].style.display="block";
    $(this).find("input")[0].focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I know I should have added this to the question but how do I get it back to the original text if the user deletes the text and then clicks away?

Comment: Ok, no need, figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(".editDIV").click(function () {
    $(this).find("span").toggle();
    $(this).find("input").val($(this).find('span').text()).toggle().focus();
});
$(".editINPUT").blur(function () {
    $(this).hide().prev().text($(this).val()).show();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7vcZT/17/)**

Comment: Thanks, voted up! But as a Jquery noob I think I will be going with the other guys solution because this one seems more complicated to understand :(

Comment: Let me know what you find complicated and I can explain it.

Comment: I really appreciate that, its just that I am justing starting out with jQuery and the code that I posted is easier to understand (for me) with having a quick look. While I think your code is probably more elegant and better the constant chaining sends my mind in a bit of a tizzie!